# Why does starting webdis connect multiple redis clients?

Tags: redis

When I begin webdis and perform a "client list" command in the redis-cli I get the following output:

```
 redis 127.0.0.1:6379> client list

 addr=127.0.0.1:44848 fd=5 name= age=13 idle=13 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=NULL

 addr=127.0.0.1:44847 fd=6 name= age=13 idle=13 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=NULL

 addr=127.0.0.1:44850 fd=7 name= age=13 idle=13 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=NULL

 addr=127.0.0.1:44851 fd=8 name= age=13 idle=13 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=NULL

 addr=127.0.0.1:44852 fd=9 name= age=13 idle=13 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=NULL

 addr=127.0.0.1:44853 fd=10 name= age=13 idle=13 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=NULL

 ddr=127.0.0.1:44854 fd=11 name= age=13 idle=13 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=NULL

 addr=127.0.0.1:44855 fd=12 name= age=13 idle=13 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=NULL

 addr=127.0.0.1:44856 fd=13 name= age=2 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=32768 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=client
```

Why do so many clients suddenly connect?  Prior to starting webdis, only a single client would appear when performing a "client list".

Answer (score 1):

Webdis creates a number of workers when it starts. These workers then connect to redis. These are the additional clients you are seeing when you do a `client list`. The single client you see before starting webdis is the `redis-cli` session you are currently running.

Comment: Yes. Webdis uses libevent and asynchronous hiredis. Opening several connections is a way to increase socket buffering (because there is one buffer per socket) and maximize Redis throughput.